# React - How to export a useRef

Tags: reactjs

I have a plenty of page that need to be focused on the header.
For this reason I created a hook:

```
const useFocusOnElement = (elementID: string) =>  {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      const elementToFocusOn = document.getElementById(elementID);
      elementToFocusOn?.focus();
    };
  }, []);
}
```

And I am calling this hook in each page:

```
useFocusOnElement("header");
```

I have been asked to use `useRef` instead of `getElementById`. I am wondering if in this case it is possible.

The header with id `header` is a child component in the JSX of the component I am using the hook on.

So if I go and edit the `<Header />` component I can easily add to it:

```
const mainHeaderRef = useRef(null);
<header id="header" tabIndex="-1" ref={mainHeaderRef}>
```

However I have no idea how to use useRef here in the hook. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you not have `useRef` outside of a component and then export the variable? Then you just import it and pass it to your header and/or hook?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea to implement this hook.

```
import * as React from 'react';

// ./useFocusOnElement.ts
const useFocusOnElement = <T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>() => {
  const elementRef = React.useRef<T>(null);

  // On mount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    elementRef.current?.focus();
  }, [elementRef.current]);

  // On unmount (uncomment if needed)
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   return () => elementRef.current?.focus();
  // }, [elementRef.current]);

  return { elementRef };
};



// ./TextField.tsx
const TextField = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});



// ./App.tsx
const App = () => {
  const { elementRef } = useFocusOnElement<HTMLInputElement>();
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField ref={elementRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```